# Unable to set img src from cordova file in Ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3, cordova-plugin-file

I'm using `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` and `cordova-plugin-file` to download user avatars and display them locally in the app. I'm successfully fetching the images and storing them in `file.dataDirectory` according to: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/ . When I check the file in the directory it says it exists...however when I try to set the absolute path of the file to an `<img>` tag I see nothing. I'm pulling in the path dynamically but even when I hardcode it...nothing.

Code for saving, loading avatars:

```
saveAvatar()
{
    var downloadUrl = this.user.avatar + "?type=small&sz=75";

    console.log("Downloading Avatar from: " + downloadUrl);
    console.log("Storing file to: " + this.file.dataDirectory + this.user.id + '/avatar.jpg');


    this.fileTransfer.download(downloadUrl, this.file.dataDirectory + this.user.id + '/avatar.jpg')
    .then((entry) => {
        console.log('~~~~~ download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('Unable to download avatar: ' + error);
    });
}

loadAvatar()
{
    var userDir = this.file.dataDirectory + this.user.id;
    var fileName = 'avatar.jpg';

    this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl(userDir)
    .then((directoryEntry: DirectoryEntry) => {
        console.log("Dir Resolved: " + directoryEntry.isDirectory);

        this.file.getFile(directoryEntry, fileName, { create: false })
        .then(file => {
            console.log("File Found: " + file.toURL());
            this.avatars[this.user.id] = file.toURL();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Unable to load avatar: ' + err));
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Unable to Resolve Directory Entry: ' + JSON.stringify(err)));
}
```

The absolute paths of the stored images are as such:

```
file:///data/user/0/package_name_here/files/1/avatar.jpg
```

or when trying on external storage:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/package_name_here/files/1/avatar.jpg
```

Any helps is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the problem. Though I was running on an android device, I was running it live in ionic which doesn't work with all cordova plugins. So instead of doing `ionic cordova run android -l -c` I just have to run it as `ionic cordova android`.

Comment: Oh..Is that mean `Plugins` are not working on the device itself with `-l`?

Comment: No I do have some plugins that work with `l`, that's what confuses me, but I have noticed there are some that only run when I do a build without it. So I don't know that there's any rhyme or reason to it but it's good to know cause it could save some headaches in the future.

Comment: Yep, It is always good to use this `ionic cordova run android --prod --device` when we needed to test `Plugins`.